# NameError: name 'nan' is not defined in Python

Tags: python, pandas, anaconda, compression

I keep getting a Name Error in anaconda and I did try to import numpy as nan the error does not change. Anybody that can point me in the right direction??

Code snipped shared below

```
import pandas as pd
import lzhw
import time

#Start counting the time
start = time.perf_counter()
#Begin compression
chunks = int(gc.shape[0] / 4) ## to have 4 chunks
compressed_chunks = lzhw.CompressedFromCSV("Fake\\File\\Path\\sensor_readings.csv", chunksize = chunks)

print("Execution Complete")
```

Comment: Your code snippet literally does not use `nan`, so nothing wrong there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to import `nan` from numpy:

```py
from numpy import nan
```

In your snippet, by running `import numpy as nan` you were making a short-hand label for `numpy`, which is usually `np`:

```py
import numpy as np
```